# binomial test for over-represented kmers in biological sequences - what is the right test?

Tags: modeling, binomial-distribution, fishers-exact-test, bioinformatics

Imagine you have a long string, like a genome, and you split it up into every overlapping word of size `n`. This is called a `kmer`.

Now, we have another set of strings that we also evaluate for `kmer` content. I want to test each `kmer` in both sets for significant over or under representation.

A somewhat-related example of how people do this sort of testing is shown [here](http://www.nature.com/nprot/journal/v8/n8/box/nprot.2013.092_BX3.html), but in my use case the binomial test falls apart. The problem is that the second set of strings is massively larger than the first set of strings.

As an example, in the data set I am looking at, the reference set of strings has one `kmer` represented `22/7243` times. The same `kmer` in the test data set is represented `2227/8883879` times, for a fraction of `0.00303` and `0.000256` times. Intuitively, this is a significant difference with a log fold-change of `2.49`, but I am looking to assign a significance test to this fold-change.

I initially was modelling this as a binomial test, where the number of successes is the number of times the data contain the kmer, or `2227` in this case, with the number of trials being the number of kmers in the dataset, `8883879`. If we then have the null model be the probability in the reference set, `p=0.00303`, we get an extremely small p-value of `1.48e-323`. Under these conditions, all comparisons are highly significant, even after a Bonferroni correction of the p-values.

My understanding here is that there are two main problems with this model. The first is that we are not sampling with replacement. There are a finite number of kmers, and we are looking at all of them in both the sample and reference. That means this is not a true Bernoulli experiment, or really something that can be modeled as one.

This led me to looking at the hypergeometric test/Fisher's exact test. But, I cannot figure a way in which I can create a 2x2 matrix from these data categories, or a way I can conceptualize this as taking out samples from a larger population, especially since the reference is a much smaller dataset.

How can I model this comparison such that I can extract a useful measure of how different one is from the other?

Comment: When you say "every overlapping word of size $n$" is that like (for n=3) splitting "sesquipedelian" into "ses", "esq", "squ", "qui" and so forth? If so, there may be a subtle issue to worry about. What is it you're looking for after you split them up? If not, what do you mean?

Comment: Yes, if n=3 then you would split it up like that. Split it up into every overlapping word of size n, then count the totals of each word found afterwards. I am looking for significant differences in word counts between one data set and the other. What is the subtle issue?

Comment: Without having gone through it carefully, I believe you have dependences between overlapping sequences that may impact the inferences you're attempting.

Comment: @Glen_b I agree, there are definitely dependencies between these. Every overlapping sequence depends on the previous. This is often modeled in biological sequence analysis as a Markov chain.